# Read Ahead issue in driver

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver

I have written a SCSI low level driver for reading mp3 CD and I can successfully mount the cd to iso9600 fs.I have a understanding that block layer will initially issue SCSI READ command with 2 or 1 block count and then/later it does a read ahead with greater number of block counts.But in my case I am always getting request of two block only in READ(10) command from block layer.
Do anyone has idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was assigning a incorrect value in the field .max_sectors in struct scsi_host_template.Because of this I was not getting block request count more that 2 from the block layer.Now on assigning a correct value I get even block request count of 30 from block layer which brings a lot of improvement in the reading speed.